# How to replace elements in a nested list python 3?

Tags: python

How to replace elements in a particular position nested list python 3? i want to insert elements in `a[1]` position. The inserted elements are in list b.

```
a = [['04\01\1997','alphanum4569874','22','4.0'],['07\01\1997','Anee_69213654','23','2.0']]

b = ['alphanum1','alphanum2']

for idx,item in enumerate(b):
    for i in b:
        a[1].append(i)

print(a)
```

Expected Output:

```
[['04\01\1997','alphanum1','22','4.0'['07\01\1997','alphanum1','23','2.0']]
```

Current Output:

```
[['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum4569874', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'Anee_69213654', '23', '2.0', 'alphanum1', 'alphanum2', 'alphanum1', 'alphanum2']]
```

Comment: I don't think that's the expected output, since the number of brackets doesn't match - did you mean `[['04\01\1997','alphanum1','22','4.0'], ['07\01\1997','alphanum2','23','2.0']]`? So, basically, you're looking to replace the 2nd element of the sublists of the first list with elements of the second list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your list `b` will always have the same number of elements as there are lists in `a` and that you always want to replace (not insert) the second element.

This works:

```
for ax, bx in zip(a, b):
    ax[1] = bx
```

First `zip` pairs up every element from `a` with the corresponding element from `b`, the for loop then gives you each pair one at a time as `ax` and `bx`. Since `ax` is a list, it's actually the list in `a` (not a copy) and with `a[1] = bx` you're just overwriting the second element in the list with `bx`.

Another way of doing it would be with a list comprehension:

```
new_a = [[ax[0], bx, *ax[2:]] for ax, bx in zip(a, b)]
```

This has the advantage of not modifying the original `a`, but gives you a new list with the replacements.

What happens here is that it still uses `zip` for the pairing, but instead of replacing `ax[1]`, it makes a new list with the first element of `ax`, followed by `bx` and then followed by the rest of `ax` from the third element onwards. Notice the `*` in there - that 'explodes' the list into its separate elements, so they can be added to the new list.

You also asked about avoiding `zip`, although I think this is a worse solution:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][1] = b[i]
```

What this does is let `i` run from `0` to the length of `a` minus one, replacing the 2nd element of each element of `a` one at a time with the matching element from `b`, by using `i` to index both `a` and `b`.

Comment: thank ypu so much. i don't know the usage of zip. so any alternative for this solution other than using zip? i want solution in simplify

Comment: I'll add an example not using `zip`, but from my perspective it would be more complicated than `zip` - `zip` is a very useful function to know, since you don't have to keep track of your position in both the lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
a = [['04\01\1997','alphanum4569874','22','4.0'],['07\01\1997','Anee_69213654','23','2.0']]
b = ['alphanum1','alphanum2']
result = [[c, d, *j] for d, [c, _, *j] in zip(b, a)]
```

Output:

```
[['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum1', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'alphanum2', '23', '2.0']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**this code works**

```
a = [['04\01\1997','alphanum4569874','22','4.0'],['07\01\1997','Anee_69213654','23','2.0']]

b = ['alphanum1','alphanum2']
c=0
for i in a:
    i[1]=b[c]
    c+=1
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum1', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'alphanum2', '23', '2.0']]
```

Comment: thank you so much but its not replacing its just appending

Comment: in question it was give to insert this is my output [['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum1', 'alphanum4569874', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'alphanum2', 'Anee_69213654', '23', '2.0']]

Comment: i want [['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum1', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'alphanum2', '23', '2.0']]

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
print([[x[0], y, *x[2:]] for x, y in zip(a, b)])
```

Output:

```
[['04\x01\x01997', 'alphanum1', '22', '4.0'], ['07\x01\x01997', 'alphanum2', '23', '2.0']]
```

Comment: thank ypu so much. i don't know the usage of zip. so any alternative for this solution other than using zip? i want solution in simplify

Comment: @suba You should learn `zip` instead, here is the documentation: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/zip.html

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is this:

```
 for item in a:
    for i in b:
       item[1].append(i)

 print (a)
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' i m getting this erro how to resolve